# How can I run one-shot external scripts using NestJS with TypeORM?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using NestJS with TypeORM, but I think my question is valid for any setup.

I've built a running server with modules and services and entities and my application is running and all is well.

Now what I would like to do is to run "one shot external scripts". Like for example, setting hide=true on some objects in the database. The quick and easy way is to just access the database directly, but then I feel all my work on setting up entities and relations was for nothing. Just bending over backwards because the framework demands it, not getting to enjoy the fruits of my labor.

How can I use my entities and services and whatnot for external code? I don't want to redeploy my app for every little script I want to run.

I come from PHP, which sits atop of Apache in my case, making it really easy to just upload a new .php file and run stuff. I don't see an easy way to do this on node frameworks.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't you think injecting scripts to run on a server from an external source is not so secure? But even so if you wanna do that then you should create an endpoint and submit your js script by uploading file and then do a command call to run `node <file_dir_where_you_saved>`.